# Can't access magic SysReq via keycode 99

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am running Kubuntu (22.04.3 LTS)* and in following [this answer to a related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/403843/584967), I found a key on my keyboard via `showkey -s` in **TTY** (<kbd>ALT+F2</kbd>) that was interpreted by my machine as 0x99 (in my case, <kbd>Fn+F12</kbd>), which I understand is the SysReq-equivalent key I need for Linux's magic SysReq commands, for which I intend to use REISUB (because my computer keeps locking up).

So when I do invoke magic SysReq in the following manner similar to test to make sure it's the right key, absolutely nothing happens:

1. Press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>.
2. Press and hold <kbd>Fn</kbd>, press and hold <kbd>F12</kbd>, then release both.
3. Press the letter or punctuation key, e.g. <kbd>F</kbd> to call oom_kill.
4. Release <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

My understanding is the above sequence *should* kill the process currently using the most memory, and I'm not running anything but Firefox and Dolphin, both of whom act as though I never hit <kbd>Fn+F12</kbd>, i.e. Firefox happily interprets the above as <kbd>Alt+F</kbd>.

What am I doing wrong?

---

* *Edits per requests for further detail:*

---

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq

244

$ cat /etc/os-release

PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Comment: Add the output of `cat /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`, please

Comment: @muru Added to post (244)

Comment: @guiverc you're absolutely correct; I forgot. Added the output of cat /etc/os-release (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS)